# jquery load to hide content

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is javascript on my webpage, but I need to hide it from my users (I don't want them to be able to see it because it contains some answers to the game.)

So I tried using Jquery .load in order to hide the content (I load the content from an external js file with that call). But it failed to load. So I tried ajax and it failed too.

Maybe the problem comes from the fact that I'm trying to load a file located in my root directory, while the original page is located in "root/public_html/main/pages":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "../../../secret_code.js",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            $("#ajaxcontent").html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

1) Why can't I load a file from the root directory with ajax or load method?
2) Is there another way around?

PS: I'm putting the file in the root directory so people can't access it directly from their browsers...

Comment: This won't actually hide anything from your users, only make it very slightly harder to find.

Comment: @jimw How is that? How can you see JS loaded asynchronously? Is there a way to hide it correctly?

Comment: Just a tip, I do this all day long, if you use .load to load a "view partial" with js in it, only the html and style script(if available) will show up in error console, the js itself is added to the page header but is not easily made visible, tho a crafty user, can always get the js on a page.  if you want real security, use $.ajax and maaintain your "answers" server side sending only what needs to be seen to the client and returning client info in order to get next answer or whatever

Comment: Adam: Well, it depends when you're loading it: after it's been loaded the user can see it - it's in the client, so he must be able to.  If you only load the answers after the user has submitted his answers, then that's not a problem, except if they can come back and try again knowing the answers to the ones they got wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1) if the file isn't accessible via web browsers, than it's not accessible via ajax (ajax is part of the web browsers

2) try `/secret_code` instead of `../../../secret_code.js`

Comment: I don't want my users to be able to have access to the JS

Comment: @AdamStrudwick if you use a js file the user can see it. There's no way to prevent it.

Comment: Sorry, the browser isn't a black box (well, IE is, but not the good ones.) Maybe you'd like to make a proprietary desktop app instead of a web page?

Comment: People can use eg the chrome inspector to see every byte that's sent by or received by the browser. Doesn't matter if its javascript. If people want to cheat badly enough, they will. Just do what's reasonable, and deal with cheaters if needed later.

Answer (score 1):

What is your system setup? Are you using a CMS?

Even if you add the javascript to the page after page load a user with a tool like firebug can go and view it. I don't think what you are doing is really going to secure it. An alternate solution is that you could minify and obfuscate the javascript that you use in your production environment. This will produce near unreadable but functioning javascript code. There are a number of tools that you can run your code through to minify and obfuscate it. Here is one tool you could use: http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/

If that isn't enough then maybe you could put the answers to the game on your serverside and pull them via ajax. I don't know your setup so I don't know if that is viable for you.

Comment: I'm on a VPS so I have full access. According to you, I should obfuscate and minify the code - and can I add an additionnal htaccess restriction to prevent users from accessing the js itself? What line would it be (I'm not very familiar with htaccess except for error pages...) Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, if the browser can access your javascript file so that you can run it then the user can too. I don't think you can grant the browser access and not the user. If you need to hide any data or logic then it will need to live in server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

You can only load files that are accessible directly from browsers, for example, `http://www.mydomain.com/secret_code.js`

If it can't be accessed directly by the browser, it can't be accessed by the browser via ajax. <strike>You can however use .htaccess to prevent users from opening up a js file directly</strike>, though that doesn't keep them from looking at it in the google chrome or firebug consoles.

If you want to keep it secret, don't let it get to the browser.

Comment: How would you prevent direct access to a script with htaccess?

Comment: Actually that isn't possible. I'm not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the URL, not the directory. Like

```
$.ajax({
        url : "http://domain.com/js/secret_code.js",

..
```

Comment: I don't want users to be able to access it directly via the Web. With your solution, they can see secret_code.js if they try to access it... by putting it in the root directory, I hide it.

Comment: Putting it in the root directory( or any other non-web-accessible directory) is the only way to prevent users from seeing the javascript. However, it also prevents your code from seeing it. There is no way to run code in the browser while hiding it.

Comment: @AdamStrudwick, There isn't a way where you can stop the user to not to see the scripts that are already loaded on them.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you load your content dynamicly, it's quite easy to see content of the file using firebug, fiddler or any kind of proxy. I suggest you to use [obfuscator](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/). It will be harder for user to find answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`jQuery.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function, it's designed for loading Javascript files over AJAX and should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery's $.getScript() method for loading external
Script files, however, you can easily see the contents of the script file using Firebug or the developer toolbar!

Answer (score 0):

**Security first**

You can't access your root directory with JavaScript because people would read out your database passwords, ftp password aso. if that would be possible.

Comment: so is there a real way to prevent JS from being accessible to users?

Comment: @AdamStrudwick Yes, however it would then not be accessible to the browser and your application (making it useless).